# SQL statement gets unexpected ';' error in PHP and MySQLi

Tags: php, mysqli

Is there anything wrong here? It gives unexpected ';' in line 7.

```
$insert_blog_details = "INSERT INTO blogs(blog_by,title,url,date,template,status)
                                              VALUES('".$_SESSION['id']."',
                                                     '".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['title'])."',
                                                     '".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['url']."',
                                                     NOW(),
                                                     '".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['template']."',
                                                     'ok')";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the ending parenthesis on the last 2 `mysqli_real_escape_string()` calls:

```
$insert_blog_details = "INSERT INTO blogs(blog_by,title,url,date,template,status)
                                          VALUES('".$_SESSION['id']."',
                                                 '".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['title'])."',
                                                 '".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['url'])."',
                                                 NOW(),
                                                 '".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['template'])."',
                                                 'ok')";
```

Answer (score 2):

You missed  `")"` in query, replace your query with this

```
$insert_blog_details = "INSERT INTO blogs (blog_by,title,url,date,template,status) VALUES('".$_SESSION['id']."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['title'])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['url'])."',NOW(),'".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['template'])."','ok')";
```

`)` missed place after **template , url** in query